# Identify 2 lines on a circle, then find length of arc of those 2 points

Tags: geometry, circles

I'm not very good at math, so please be kind.

Let's say that i have the a line called `q` and that line goes through the circle `C`

The line has been drawn with 2 coordinates, which then I calculate the angle of the line using arctan and then drawing it with cos and sin (you might ask yourself why i do that but its necessary)

So now what I need to figure out is the 2 points where `q` intercepts the Lines of circle `C`, then calculate both ways around the circle and be able to set points around the circle, as i would wish to

Here's a little picture i tried to do idk if it helps

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jWzJ.png (i cant post images yet bruh)

if you have any other questions and you feel very kind, feel free to ask instead of giving me a downvote or something idk

Comment: By two coordinates of a line, do you mean the slope and the y-intercept?

Comment: @mathlander well what i originally used to draw the line was using 2 coordinates, then taking arctan of y2-y1, x2-x1, then using the angle i got to draw the line: so x1 and y1 is the origin, then x2 = x1 + l * cos(arctan), y2=y1 + l * sin(arctan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the two coordinate points you use to draw q, you can find the equation of q (y=mx+b, with m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)) (I don't know how to write equations on math exchange I'm sorry.) If you know the coordinate of the center of your circle and its radius, you can find the equation of the circle (x−x1)^2+(y−y1)^2=r2.
If you want to find the points where they intersect, you can set these two equations equal to each other, and solve to find the coordinates of your two intersection points.

Finding the centre angle between the two intersection points now is a bit more difficult. You can take one of the line segments between your center and a intersection point as 'new' x-axis with the origin of your coordinate system coinciding with your circle center. The you can describe the position of your second intersection point in terms of this new coordinate system and then use arctan(y/x) for you center angle.

Now for the arc you just multiply this center angle by the radius of the circle.